# Required Tags when asking a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

There was a discussion a while back about including the Joomla version as a tag when asking a question. As some may know, I am all for this.

Those who have already asked question on this meta will already know that you're **required** to add either the [bug](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), [discussion](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [support](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) tag.

So on JSE, should the version tag, such as [cms-3.3](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms-3.3) be required when asking a question? This will ensure that users do not forget to do so and will save other asking which version the OP is using.

**A question for the moderators:**

If this feature possible on a non-meta StackExchange site?

Answer (score 1):

Off-topic, but the tags mentioned are already created on meta. You should be able to add / propose a new tag if you feel like it (not sure about permissions), so I don't think it's enforced to use one of the tags, you just need to use one, whatever.

Regarding the website, I would prefer to have tags instead of mentions of the Joomla version in the post. There are two issues:

1. I don't know if the SE platform supports that (technically)
2. Some questions are not specifically referring to a Joomla version. [Example 1.](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/945/which-is-the-best-certification-course-offered-in-joomla-for-professional-web-de)

Nevertheless I would use the tags rather wisely. Something like `cms-2.5.20` is way too detailed. At least from my experience on SO, questions that have an issue with just an specific version are the exception and not the rule. Very generic questions could have `cms-3.x` and to be more specific it can be `cms-3.3` etc.

Comment: Ahh yes you make a good point about questions that don't rely on a specific Joomla version, in which case, there should be a fallback imo

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we want to enforce a cms version tag. THere are questions which don't belong to a particular Joomla version because they are more general ones.